# Jquery run one scrpict file after another file completes

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I have an html page with 2 scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script
```

script1.js:

```
            function one () {

                    $.ajax({

                        type: 'get',
                        url: 'one.txt',
                        success:function (data) {

                            alert(data);

                            }           
                        });
        };

        one();
```

script2.js:

```
alert('Script1 Has Completed!");
```

because script1 is asynchronous, script2 loads before script1.

How can I make **script2 run only after scrpipt1** has executed "alert(data)"?
(I want to **keep "scrpit1.js" and "script2.js" files separated**).

UPD: maybe misunderstanding. I want first run "alert(data)" from script1, and then "alert("Script1 Has Completed!")" from script2 (I want to run the last alert EXACTLY from script2, not scrpipt1!!!).

Comment: Don't use `<script>` tags, but load the scripts dynamically and trigger the loading of the second on the `one()` promise done.

Comment: Change alert(data) to load the script2 into the page

Comment: you can `trigger` a custom event after script1 runs. set your script 2 to listen on the event, then execute your code. 
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

run your code depending to returns of first for eg.

```
            function one () {

                    $.ajax({

                        type: 'get',
                        url: 'one.txt',
                        success:function (data) {

                            alert(data);
                            alert('Script One Has Completed!");

                            }           
                        });
        };

        one();
```

but the best choice is to use [Promise](https://www.promisejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Your second script will be executed directly, it wont wait until you ajax call has finished. what you need is a function you can call, it wont be executed directly but when it is called, but it has to be defined before it is called

```
  function two(){
    alert("ajax call done");
  }
  function one () {

    $.ajax({

        type: 'get',
        url: 'one.txt',
        success:function (data) {

            two();

            }           
        });
  };

  one();
```

this is called procedural coding

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like so

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "script2.js";

...
success:function (data) {
  alert(data);
  $("head").append(script);//$("body")
}
...
```